# ultrasonic sensor giving wrong distance when working with tmrpcm library?

Tags: arduino

I am trying to measurer distance with ultrasonic sensor, for each 10 centimeters a wav file is playing from micro SD. the ultrasonic sensor is working fine alone. but when connected with micro SD and by using tmrpcm library to play sound at some range the measurement is giving wrong distances.
this is my code.

```
#include "SD.h"
#include "TMRpcm.h"
#include "SPI.h"

const int EchoM = 6;
const int TriggerM = 5;

float distanceM;
unsigned long durationM;

const int SD_ChipSelectPin = 4;
TMRpcm tmrpcm;

void setup()
{
  tmrpcm.speakerPin = 9;
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(TriggerM, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(TriggerM, LOW);
  pinMode(EchoM, INPUT);

  if (!SD.begin(SD_ChipSelectPin)) {
    Serial.println("SD fail");
    return;
  }
  tmrpcm.setVolume(5);
}

void loop() {

  digitalWrite(TriggerM, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds (50);
  digitalWrite(TriggerM, LOW);
  durationM = pulseIn(EchoM, HIGH);
  distanceM = durationM / 58.0;


  if (distanceM >= 1 && distanceM <= 9 ) {
    Serial.println(distanceM, 1);
    delay(900);
    m5();
    delay(800);
  }

  if (distanceM >= 10 && distanceM <= 19 ) {
    Serial.println(distanceM, 1);
    delay(900);
    m15();
    delay(800);
  }

  if (distanceM >= 20 && distanceM <= 29 ) {
    Serial.println(distanceM, 1);
    delay(900);
    m25();
    delay(800);
  }

  if (distanceM >= 30 && distanceM <= 39 ) {
    Serial.println(distanceM, 1);
    delay(900);
    m35();
    delay(800);
  }
  if (distanceM >= 40 && distanceM <= 49 ) {
    Serial.println(distanceM, 1);
    delay(900);
    m45();
    delay(800);
  }

}
const int vdelay = 400;
void m5() {
  tmrpcm.play("m5.wav");
  delay (vdelay);

}
void m15() {
  tmrpcm.play("m15.wav");
  delay (vdelay);
}
void m25() {
  tmrpcm.play("m25.wav");
  delay (vdelay);
  
}
void m35() {
  tmrpcm.play("m35.wav");
  delay (vdelay);
  
}
void m45() {
  tmrpcm.play("m45.wav");
  delay (vdelay);
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. the problem was the pulseIn is not accurate when there are multiple libraries. so, I used NewPing library instead and it worked just as I wanted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).